# How to throw an error if a promise isn't resolved after a certain time

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise, settimeout

I want to throw an error after a certain amount of time ONLY if the promise hasn't been resolved yet. Something like

```
promiseDelayReject(delay){ //set timeout omitted
     var t = (return value of $.ajax)
     if(timeUp)
          throw errorAndRejectPromise;
     else
          keepGoingAndResolvePromise
```

Some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call the `reject` parameter from your `Promise` inside the `setTimeout`.  If whatever you wanted to do is done before, cancel your timeout with `clearTimeout()`

```js
var t;
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  
  t = setTimeout(function(){
    reject('Too late !');
  },5000);

  // ... Do your second promise here
  var p2 = new Promise(function(res,rej){
    //If you thing is done, then cancel the timeout :
    //if(...){
    //  clearTimeout(t);
    //  res();
    //}
  });
  
}).catch(function(error){
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: It's ok but not absolutely correct, i need a promise INSIDE ANOTHER PROMISE, the timeout will be on the outer promise and i have to check if the inner promise has been resolved

Comment: Man as i said before, using a timer promise and using Promise.race() with my original promise it's a much cleaner way to do what i need to do, thanks anyway dude!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so we need to be able to tell if the promise is resolved first, this doesnt exist in the native Promise API but we can do it with something like:

```
//unfortunately the native Promise API
//doesnt have an isResolved() | isAccepted() | isRejected() method
//so we have to monkey our way around it
function isResolved(promise) {
  var resolved = true

  promise.then(function(){ resolved = false })
         .catch(function(){ resolved = false })

  return resolved
}
```

Then you can use it inside your `setTimeout` to throw:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  try {
    if(!isResolved(prommise)) throw "stuff"
  } catch(e) {
    //do what you wanted here
  }
}, delay)
```

Although notice the `try catch` has to be inside `setTimeout` since you cant throw to outside of the function it recieves. it would be much better if you could use a callback or promise chain to handle the error you want to throw

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i don't want that my promise will be resolved AFTER a timeout, i need my promise to keep going and AFTER the timeout, if my promise is still processing, i want to throw an exception

Comment: @JSelser Why would you wait for the end of your timeout to check if the promise was done ? Just cancel your timeout when your promise is resolved, it will get rid of all this dirty code.

Comment: @JSelser it's still not quite right, i don't want my code to be stuck there, i want it to keep running until something happens

Comment: @TheRev I'd love to fix it, where does it gets stuck?

Comment: @JSelser it gets stuck in the setTimeout, the timeout should be like inside the promise, i found a better way using 2 promises, my promise and a "timer promise" launched toghether with Promise.race()

Thanks anyway

Comment: Glad you found your solution, I dont see how you are making your code get stuck though. But yhea, using a promise library with more features is a better solution at the cost of an additional library